# Django compressor is not effective

Tags: django, compression, django-compressor

I've successfully set everything in the setting.py and when running `py manage.py compress` it runs without errors and I see that 2 blocks have been compressed.

Here is the template:

```py
{% compress css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'project/main.css' %}">
{% endcompress %}
```

When opening the site from the browser I see something happened (the filename changed to `output.6a62b0ce8790.css` and the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` is also shows up). However the filesize is not changing.

`COMPRESSION_ENABLED = True` is set and I also use `DEBUG = True` (I don't know if it matters).

Comment: The compressed filesize, or the file you eventually receive at the browser side. Note that the browser will enflate the file again, and thus the file size at the browser side is not the size that has been downloaded.

Comment: the downloaded size doesn't change too, but it should